# Mark as a validation routine

Tags: java, appscan

There is documentation on marking up methods as validation routines below.

https://help.hcltechsw.com/appscan/Source/9.0.3/topics/input_output_tracing_example2_trace.html

However I'm using cloud.appscan.com, and on the ValidationRequired->Details->Method, it shows the source/sink flow but there is no ability to drill down any methods and flag validation methods.  How can I do this on the cloud version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install a plugin and annotate methods.  There are three annotation available as part of the com.static.analyzer.annotation.jar package.

```
@ValidatorMethod
@SuppressSecurityTrace
@CallbackMethod
```

This jar is only found in the SAClientUtil_[VERSION]_[OS].zip which is included available on their cloud.appscan.com site as part of their "ASoC client tools" within their downloadable "plugins and apis".

https://help.hcltechsw.com/appscan/ASoC/src_java_annotations.html?hl=validator#src_java_annotations__validator_method